# How do I increase the distance between the text and the image in an Android TabActivity?

Tags: java, android, tabs

I have a Tabactivity with several Tabs and the text is overlaying the images in the tabs. How do I increase the distance between the image and the tabs ?

Comment: Please post your code. Without it how can anyone help you. But as per requirement you can set padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by simply adding empty transparent space at the bottom of the images which is now overlapped by the text but that doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use your own drawable with any paddings (10dp). You can use images for this, or you can create your tabs' backgrounds via xml's, say inside a  root element:

```
<layer_list>
    <item android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:bottom="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        [..]
        </shape>
    </item>
    [..]
</layer_list>
```